# App Engine Python Development Server + Taskqueue + Backend

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm using GAE Python 2.7 with the local development server. I have configured a backend

```
backends:
- name: worker
  class: B1
  options: dynamic
```

and I'm using the default taskqueue. Everything works fine and the backend and taskqueue are visible at the SDK console. Also the local development work starts without any errors:

```
Multiprocess Setup Complete:
Remote API Server [http://localhost:9200]
App Instance [http://localhost:9000]
Backend Instance: worker.0 [http://localhost:9100]
Backend Balancer: worker [http://localhost:9199]
```

BUT if I try to address the backend via a task

```
taskqueue.add(url='/xyz', method='POST', target='worker', params={'a':'b'})
```

this error raises:

```
ERROR An error occured while sending the task "task1" (Url: "/backend/languages/create_database/") in queue "default". Treating as a task error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/taskqueue_stub.py", line 1884, in ExecuteTask
    connection.endheaders()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 937, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 797, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 759, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 740, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 553, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

I'm using 'localhost' and can't see any reason why it fails. Some ideas / solutions? Any startup-parameter missing or somethin like that?

Thanks

Comment: Can you edit your `taskqueue.add` statement?

Comment: Of course I could execute the statement without any "target", it's running without any errors. But my goal is the execution on the backend server :-)

Answer (score 8):

It's a bug in [`taskqueue.py`](http://code.google.com/searchframe#Qx8E-7HUBTk/trunk/python/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/taskqueue.py&q=taskqueue.py%20package:googleappengine%5C.googlecode%5C.com&l=827), it misses a case to distinguish between production and the development environment.

In production, it does the right thing by concatenating the `target` with the `hostname`.

In development, that doesn't work and will produce the error you reported when trying to resolve `worker.localhost` address.

Instead it should set the task host to the `ip:port` dev_appserver is running the backend on.

There is already a [bug](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=5105) in the public issue tracker that has been escalated to the engineering team.

Feel free to star it if you want to be notified about updates.

Comment: So any fix for that? Or we can't develop anymore on the dev server?

Comment: You should star http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=5105 to be notified about update regarding this issue.

Comment: @JimmyKane, please see below a small workaround that helps me to debug backend services locally.

Answer (score 1):

There is one workaround that helps me debug locally:

```
if os.environ['SERVER_SOFTWARE'].startswith('Development'):
    taskqueue.add(url='/task', params={...})
else:    
    taskqueue.add(url='/task', params={...}, target='backendservername')
```

In this case, if we debug locally, we run the task in the regular task queue. If we put this code into App Engine it will start the task using a backend server.

Comment: Are you specifying the PORT number using this if statement?

Comment: @Andrew, no, I don't specify any port numbers.

Comment: In that case, i don't entirely understand the solution. In the example above, the task will still be directed to port 80 (as opposed to 8080). I though you were specifying the port via target='localhost:8080', but you're not taking this approach... I guess I don't understand how "taskqueue.add(url='/task', params={...})" solves this issue.

Comment: @Andrew, it is not a solution. It is a workaround. The main idea in this code that we don't use a backend at all. We use regular task queue.