# Task failed to execute on Development server

Tags: google-app-engine

On Development Server, whenever I add an taskqueue

```
taskqueue.add(queue_name='default', url='/_tasks/do_something', params={'key': 1})
```

The following error occurred

```
taskqueue_stub.py:1974] Task task1 failed to execute. This task will retry in 819.200 seconds
```

After getting some hint from this post:
http://www.rogerthat.net/2012/03/27/google-app-engine-push-task-queues-the-development-environment/

I suspect it could be something to do with the hostname. I am using http://test.me:8088 (where test.me point to 127.0.0.1 using host file). The problem goes away when I change the hostname (test.me) to "localhost".

I can't just use localhost due to some app configuration issue.
The code edit rogerthat.net point out is no longer valid.

Any other solution?

Comment: What do you see in your error logs?

Comment: Does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13273067/app-engine-python-development-server-taskqueue-backend ?. I got the same with backends

Comment: @Andrei Volgin The error message shown is as per above: Task task1 failed to execute. This task will retry in 819.200 seconds

Comment: @Jimmy Kane it is hostname related, fixed on 1.7.7, but probably not for my case. Found a relevant issue tracker, no solutions: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7248

Comment: Typically you would see a stack trace that gives you a cause - why a task failed to execute.

Comment: @Andrei Volgin it's usually true for Exception error, but not in this case. Just a repeated one liner.

Comment: More info: the trigger point is because I am using Flask's subdomain support by specifying SERVER_NAME (https://flask.readthedocs.org/en/0.6/config/#builtin-configuration-values), while I believe taskqueue on Development use localhost, thus the task url is unreachable.